# Detect with shell if one and only one docker container is up with this while script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I'm trying to detect if one and only one container is up in a linux environment.

I'm using the below code because the output can be sometimes "" (empty string) and sometimes more than 8 chars (more containers up).

But I cannot make it work this bash/shell script:

```bash
while [ ${#"$(docker ps -q --filter name=image-name)"} != 8 ]; do echo wait && sleep 1; done && echo OK
```

it errors with:

```
-bash: ${#"$(docker ps -q --filter name=image-name)"}: bad substitution
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${#...}` requires the name of a parameter, not an arbitrary expression. You'll need a temporary variable.

```
while t=$(docker ps -q --filter name=image-name); [ "${#t}" -ne 8 ]; do
    echo wait
    sleep 1
done
echo OK
```